# Looking for a field isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory

I am looking for a field that is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}$. Could someone kindly give an example, or construct one such field?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Q$ is one such field...

Comment: @Mariano- I am looking for non-trivial examples.

Comment: Take $\mathbb Q$ and color all the elements blue. That’s as nontrivial as you can get.

Comment: Can you expand on what you would accept as "non-trivial"?

Comment: Let $\alpha: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection and define operations $\times_\alpha, +_\alpha$ on $\mathbb{N}$ so that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism of fields. Your question should be more specific and well defined, otherwise I would not be surprised if your question is closed.

Comment: Well if you can find a ring $R$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ you can take $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ and I *think* this will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $F$ is a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ via the map $\phi : \mathbb{Q} \to F.$

We usually denote the multiplicative identity of any field with $F$ by the symbol $1.$ We also write $1+1=2, 1+1+1=3$ etc, and often we write $ab^{-1}$ as $a/b.$  For clarify I'll use a subscript $F$ for elements inside $F.$

Now since $\phi$ is a field homomorphism, $\phi(1) = 1_F.$ Since $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x) + \phi(y),$ we have $\phi(2) = 1_F + 1_F =2_F.$ Similarly, $\phi(n)=n_F,$ so again by the field homomorphism axioms, $\phi(n/m) =n_F m_F^{-1} = n_F/m_F.$

Now since $\phi$ is surjective, every element of $F$ looks like $n_F/m_F,$ with these symbols not satisfying any special relation like $1+1+1=0$ as that would contradict injectivity (this means $F$ has *characteristic* $0$).

So basically, if we agree to standard notations for all fields: write the multiplicative identities as $1$, $1+1=2,$ $ab^{-1} = a/b,$ then any field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ must be exactly $\mathbb{Q}$ itself! Any "other" field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ will simply be $\mathbb{Q}$ rewritten with strange notation.

Comment: It could, I believe, be legitimately argued that the statement "Any 'other' field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ will simply be $\mathbb{Q}$ rewritten with strange notation" may be applied to *any* isomorphism of fields, or (with suitable minor modifications) to *any* isomorphism of any structures whatever!  But then that's the beauty of abstraction! ;-)

Comment: @RobertLewis I should been clearer about what I was trying to get at. Indeed, we can view two isomorphic structures as the same but differently labelled. However, my emphasis was that in this special case, using standard notation, any field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ must have the **same** underlying set. The set of symbols denoting elements in $F$ and the rules defining addition/multiplication are identical! So if you run across a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q},$ you will know. You can't miss it. This is different to e.g. $k[X,Y]/(Y-X^2)\cong k[T]$ as rings, where one may well not notice.

Comment: This stuff gets into deep water fast, since it seems (to me at least) to border on philosophical issues regarding identity, naming, distinction and identity (again!) etc. etc. etc.  Anyway, rather than ponder this stuff at length *right now*, I think I will just keep on mathematicing, and save worries about whether is only one $\Bbb Q$ or many isomorphic fields each of which *looks* like $\Bbb Q$ for a later date.  But I appreciate your appreciation of this matter!  Cheers! ;-)